# Question about VTPv3 Pruning

Tags: networking, cisco

I have found that I can get extended VLANs to propagate with VTP using version 3, but I noticed that it still does not prune extended VLANs.  I tried to add an extended VLAN to the prune eligible list but received an error:

```
CAT_3750-48-TS(config-if)#switchport trunk pruning vlan 1120
Command rejected: Bad VLAN list - character #5 (EOL) delimits a VLAN
number (1120) out of the range 1 to 1005.
CAT_3750-48-TS(config-if)#
```

Is there a way to allow VTP to prune extended VLANs?
If not what is the point of supporting extended VLANs to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 'spanning-tree extend system-id' enabled.  Also, what does 'show vtp status' show?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly seems that VTPv3 support pruning only for "canonical VLAN".

Soruce:
http://forum.internetworkexpert.com/forums/t/9371.aspx

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/catos/8.x/configuration/guide/vtp.html#wp1020748

> *Note VTP pruning still applies only to VLANs 1 to 1005, and VLANs 1002 to 1005 are still reserved and cannot be modified.*